# How can I beat the game?

Tags: speed-warp

After unlocking Death Duel, each boss you beat unlocks a new boss.  I just beat "The Developper" and now I'm trying to beat "The Game".

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do to beat is though.  Attacking doesn't work.  Ranged attacks are no good.  So how am I supposed to beat it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it say when you try and hit it with projectiles?

> What kind of combinations are good at beating the game?

> Konami Code?

> Press ↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A